How to change color for db and menus on Windows 11 from default settings?
I am experiencing difficulties with a selection background that is extremely faint and lacks distinctiveness. Could you please provide some guidance on where and how to modify the color settings for mouse-hover, selections, and completed menus on Windows 11, reminiscent of the classic Windows XP aesthetic?

Have you looked at using different Windows themes from Settings?

Yes. I have tried the settings on Windows 11. But they are not the same like Win XP, that was a bit more elaborate.
